# Font in R Script

Tags: rstudio

While working in RStudio, I accidentally changed the font. (It is changed in my console,the environment tab, everywhere.) I can't seem to figure out how to change in back to the default font. How do you change the font back in an R script?

Comment: are you in RStudio or R? if RStudio try tools>global options > appearance > font

Comment: RStudio. Got it. Thank you!

Comment: @jeremycg: please add that as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you may have already solved this for the time being, but I will answer for documentation purposes:

In order to change the font of the R's console and the font used in your scripts, you have to click on the `Tools\Global options...` menu and then change to `Appearance` tab (see screenshot below)

[image: Appearance tab]